# Android studio set background color of view

Tags: java, android-studio, view, colors, background

So I have a code

```
view.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.blue, null));
```

And I have an error

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable
                        view.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.blue, null));
```

So I have another code

```
view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, android.R.color.blue));
```

And I have another error

```
error: cannot find symbol
                        view.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, android.R.color.blue));
```

So I have
**another**
code

```
view.setBackground(android.R.color.blue);
```

and I have another error

```
error: cannot find symbol
                        view.setBackground(android.R.color.blue);
```

Please help. I'm drowning in errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.blue));
```